# set Image source from a resource dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a wpf application ,in which I have a tabcontrol ,I set its ItemTemplate from an external resource dictionary,in that template I have an Image Control which I bind to a string Property 'ImagePath' in my ViewModel and using a converter I convert 'ImagePath' into new bitmapImage .I created my converter class instance in the external resource disctinary. I merged the external dictionary in my App.xaml

Here is my External Resource Dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:RH_Maize.Helper">

<helpers:ImageSourceConverter x:Key="ImageSourceConverter" />

<DataTemplate x:Key="ClosableTabItemTemplate">
    <StackPanel Width="155"
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    Height="35">
        <Image Height="25"
            Width="30"
            Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath,Converter={ StaticResource ImageSourceConverter}}"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DisplayName}"
            Width="100" Height="27" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="15" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"
            Content="x" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Here is my Converter class :

```
 public class ImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType == typeof(ImageSource))
        {
            if (value is string)
            {
                string str = (string)value;
                return new BitmapImage(new Uri(str, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            }
            else if (value is Uri)
            {
                Uri uri = (Uri)value;
                return new BitmapImage(uri);
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My ViewModel Property is :

```
  private string _ImagePath;
    public string ImagePath
    {
        get
        {
            return _ImagePath;
        }
        set
        {
            _ImagePath = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => ImagePath);
        }
    }
```

My problem is that the converter classes convert method is not invoking at all .Whats wrong with my code ?

Comment: You don't need that converter at all, as WPF has built-in type conversion from `string` and `Uri` to `ImageSource`. Remove it and then check if the `ImagePath` property getter is called or not.

Comment: When a `Binding` doesn't work, you need to debug the situation. Do you have an errors in the Output Window in Visual Studio? Have you put a breakpoint in the `ImageSourceConverter.Convert` method (outside the `if` statement)?

Comment: @Sheridan ,How to debug binding values

Comment: First, I'd do what I just suggested. Then if you're still having problems, you could follow the advise in the [Debug Databinding Issues in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/DebugDataBinding.html) article on the WPF Tutorial .NET website.